# The following series converge or diverge? Prove it!

Tags: convergence-divergence

Does the following series converge or diverge?
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{-n+\sqrt{n}} n^4$$

I tried using the root test to prove convergence.
So we take  $\quad\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}\quad$, but I don't know how to find this limit. I tried with derivatives but in the end I can't find a solution.
Could someone please help me?

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Sum%5B%5C%2840%29Power%5Be%2C-n%2BSqrt%5Bn%5D%5DPower%5Bn%2C4%5D%5C%2841%29%2C%7Bn%2C1%2Cinfinity%7D%5D) says 241.1710913

Comment: It will converge.  The handwavy explanation is that $e^{-n}$ dominates everything else pictured.  A less handwavy explanation might have you compare to more wellbehaved series, for example rather than the term $e^{-n+\sqrt{n}}$ could you compare to $e^{-n+\frac{1}{2}n}$?  To handle the fact that there is the $n^4$ there, can you make an argument about derivatives or the like, or as you suggest... using a test like root tests or ratio tests?

Comment: I think the ratio test might prove a little easier to apply here.

Comment: @AmiAshman: And as always the Mathematica group is off by a factor of 5. Lordy!

Answer (score 1):

Let us rewrite the term a little bit. If we apply the $n$-th root, we get

$$(e^{-n + \sqrt n} n^4)^\frac{1}{n} = (e^{-1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt n}}) \cdot n^\frac{1}{n} \cdot n^\frac{1}{n} \cdot n^\frac{1}{n}\cdot n^\frac{1}{n}.$$

First, it is well-known that $ n^\frac{1}{n}$ tends to 1 for $n \to \infty$. Second, since the exponential function is continues, we get
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \exp\left({-1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt n}}\right) =  \exp\left( \lim_{n \to \infty} {-1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt n}}\right) = \exp(-1),$$
where we used that $\frac{1}{\sqrt n}$ converges to 0.
Now, we combine these two facts with the product rule of limits (i.e. $\lim a_n \cdot b_n = \lim a_n \cdot \lim b_n$ if both limits exist) to get
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}  (e^{-1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt n}}) \cdot n^\frac{1}{n} \cdot n^\frac{1}{n} \cdot n^\frac{1}{n}\cdot n^\frac{1}{n} = \exp(-1) \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 = \exp(-1) < 1$$
Thus, we can use the root test to show convergence.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ratio test
$$a_n=e^{-n+\sqrt{n}}\, n^4 \qquad \implies \log(a_n)=-n+\sqrt{n}+4\log(n)$$
$$\log(a_{n+1})-\log(a_n)=\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}+4 \log (n+1)-4 \log (n)-1$$ Using Taylor series
$$\log(a_{n+1})-\log(a_n)=-1+\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{n}}+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=e^{\log(a_{n+1})-\log(a_n)}=\frac 1 e+\frac{1}{2 e\sqrt{n}}+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$